# how to print out values from vector under a struct

Tags: c++, vector

in my code i am unable to print out the value assigned into the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
using std::stringstream;



string pMem, comment, sGen, val,input,id,size,inits,incs;

double pmemSize =0;

char t[10], m[256],init[10],inc[10];


struct rootset {
  double totSize;
  double *rStrtPtr;
  double *rEndPtr;
  vector<double> physicalM; /* This is the size of physical memory i need to assign*/

  struct generations {
    double totSize;
    const char *genStrtPtr;
    const char *genEndPtr; 
    int numOfGen;
    string genName;

    struct object {
      double objSize;
      const char *objStrtPtr;
      const char *objEndPtr;
      string id;
      char markBit;
      char objPtr;
    };

    struct freeList {
      double freeSpace;
      int flNumb; 
    };
  };
};
int main()
{
  int pmemSize;
  cout<<" ENter the size "<<endl;
  cin >> pmemSize;
  vector<rootset> pRootSet;
  pRootSet.push_back(rootset());
  pRootSet[0].totSize = pmemSize;
  pRootSet[0].physicalM.reserve(pmemSize);

   for (int s=0; s<pmemSize; ++s)
      pRootSet[0].physicalM[0] =s;

  vector<double>::iterator it;

  for(it = pRootSet[0].physicalM.begin(); it!= pRootSet[0].physicalM.end(); ++it) 
      cout <<"Printing it: " <<(*it)<<endl;
}
```

I basically need to assign some space in the physical memory provided by the user. I thought i'd use vectors. But i am unable to print the values i enter into the physicalM.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled index of physicalM:

```
for (int s=0; s<pmemSize; ++s)
      pRootSet[0].physicalM[s] =s;
                          ^^^^
```

Comment: Sure.. Thanks. And how do i print it out using the iterator? Im clearly doing it wrong here..

Comment: @BrownieTuffy Your output loop with the iterator looks correct. Does it produce anything wrong? What exactly?

Comment: And you should use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`, or `push_back()` the values as suggested in answer above.

Comment: great. Thank you... The iterator loop was correct after i made the edits you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are not storing the values into physicalM properly.  Use:

```
    pRootSet[0].physicalM.push_back(s);
```

Then your iterator should appropriately print them.